# Issue in creating openstack vm as salve in jenkins using jclouds plugin

Tags: jclouds

I'm facing problem in creating a slave machine using jclouds plugin.
machine get added in slave list but as an off-line. And  on relach-slave following error are coming.

> Launching slave agent: cd /tmp && java  -jar slave.jar
>
> ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in
>
> INFO: <<
> (ubuntu:rsa[fingerprint(43:1a:6e:3a:1b:9c:6f:67:4a:c3:e1:9c:1f:be:52:51),sha1(cf:17:36:58:2f:12:97:76:bf:cf:a7:10:97:1c:5e:c4:91:92:8d:3f)]@192.168.1.108:22)
> error acquiring SFTPClient() (attempt 1 of 7): Timeout expired

Comment: From the error it seems the image does not have a sftp server available?

Comment: @zacksh => i'm using ubuntu cloud image and it has openssl-server installed. still facing this issue.

Comment: What happens when you try to manually ssh into the image, any problems ?